# cdev file operations initialization in LDD3 scull example

Tags: linux, drivers

Learning about Device Driver in Linux. Reading Linux Device Drivers online. The book discusses the following code

```
static void scull_setup_cdev(struct scull_dev *dev, int index)
{
    int err, devno = MKDEV(scull_major, scull_minor + index);

    cdev_init(&dev->cdev, &scull_fops);
    dev->cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    dev->cdev.ops = &scull_fops;
    err = cdev_add (&dev->cdev, devno, 1);
    /* Fail gracefully if need be */
    if (err)
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Error %d adding scull%d", err, index);
}
```

Don't `cdev_init(&dev->cdev, &scull_fops)` and `dev->cdev.ops = &scull_fops` do the same thing?

Comment: No, check `cdev_init` source: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/fs/char_dev.c#L626

Comment: @myaut I should have rephrased it. Doesn't `cdev_init` already initialize `fops` for `cdev`, just like in http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/fs/char_dev.c#L631.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, they don't do the same insofar `cdev_init(&dev->cdev, &scull_fops)` does more than just associate `scull_fops` with the `cdev` instance. However, as you have noticed already yourself by looking into the [kernel source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/char_dev.c#L479), the two structs passed to `cdev_init`, `cdev` and `file_operations`, do indeed get associated by it. That's why `dev->cdev.ops = &scull_fops` is in fact redundant.

However, if you would have used `cdev_alloc` to allocate memory for a `cdev` at runtime, then you would have to associate a `file_operations` instance with it manually (e.g., by means of the redundant line):

```c
struct cdev *cdev_ptr = cdev_alloc();

if (cdev_ptr != NULL) 
{
  cdev_ptr->ops = &scull_fops; 
}
else 
{
  /* cdev_alloc() failed */ 
}
```

My guess would be that this is the reason behind the redundant line appearing in the example code in the book.